# Hapi/Joi Validation: How to process text to a specific format

Tags: node.js, express, validation, hapi.js

Is it possible to pass a string to hapi/joi and for it to process it and return a required format? For example consider the code below:

```
const acceptedCitiesSchema = Joi.object({
    isCapitalCity: Joi.boolean().default(true),
    cityName: Joi.string().valid('MyCity', 'YourCity').required(),
})
```

How can I make it that even if a user inputs `'myCity'` or `'yourCity'` joi automatically converts them to a format that the first word is capitalized(`'MyCity'` and `'YourCity'` respecively). And returns the desired results? Is it possible to achieve this using hapi/joi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    isCapitalCity: Joi.boolean().default(true),
    cityName: Joi.string().valid('MyCity', 'YourCity').insensitive().required()
})
```

And while validating with schema, you can use the `convert:true` option as:

```
schema.validate({"cityName": "myCity"}, {"convert": true})
```

Alternatively, you can directly provide additional preferences to convert the Joi validated object in the schema:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    isCapitalCity: Joi.boolean().default(true),
    cityName: Joi.string().valid('MyCity', 'YourCity').insensitive().prefs({convert:true}).required()
})
```

Here is a link to working example: https://repl.it/repls/HarmfulEvenPhases